# Active Record tree model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ancestry

I've searched around for quite some time but couldn't find any information on what I wanted to achieve.

I'm trying to achieve something such as a grandfather-father-child [tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOV4E.png). I've set up my model/migration using the ancestry gem and it's working as intended. I can create children and see the entire subtree by calling `subtree` on the model.

I have a separate table, such as messages. I want to be able to see all messages for say **2-2** and their descendants (2-2-1, 2-2-2, 2-2-2-1, 2-2-2-2). Similarly when checking messages for **2-2-2-2** I would only expect those to be shown as it has no subtree/children.

I also need to only operate within a given root id (such as 1 or 2).

I've tried the following to achieve this:

**migration**

```
create_table :customers do |t|
  t.string :name, null: false
end

create_table :messages do |t|
  t.belongs_to :customer, index: true

  t.datetime :created_at
  t.string :message, null: false
end

add_column :customers, :ancestry, :string
add_index :customers, :ancestry
```

**model**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

**current implementation**

```
subtree_ids = Customer.find(customer_id).subtree.find(sub_customer).subtree_ids
Message.where(customer_id: subtree_ids)
```

This works, however it executes 4 queries as it need to find the customer id, find the subaccount in its subtree, retrieve the subtree ids available and then pass them to messages to search inside that array of customer ids.

I can bump this down to 2 queries, one for getting the subtree_ids for a given sub_customer and then passing them into the messages. However I need to ensure that it operates within a given customer_id.

Any help / pseudo-code on how to achieve or optimize is much appreciated, I'm quite new to AR/SQL.

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why do you need a deeply nested hierarchy for customer records?

Comment: I want to be able to have a recursive customer, so a customer can be a parent of another customer (so the top customer can see all of their descendants, however the child can not see its parent). I'm not sure if the approach I'm taking is smart in this regard. The idea is that a customer can have a huge tree if they want to (not likely and at most 1 or 2 levels deep).

Comment: If the use case is keeping track of referrals you might want to simply use a join table which links two Customers together since its more of an incidental relationship and not a true hierarchy such as a family tree or a tree of nodes in a CMS.

Comment: the use case is whereby an account can create a subaccount, the subaccount can create its own subaccount and so on (any account should only be able to see the tree below itself (including itself)).